# JACK not working in fresh Ubuntu Studio 17.04 install

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, ubuntu-studio, jack

I recently installed Ubuntu Studio for the first time a few days ago. I did not get around to even testing any audio software on it for the first few days as I was troubleshooting other problems, customizing my desktop, etc. So when I realized that JACK did not work, I assumed that it still worked out of the box in a fresh Ubuntu Studio install, and that something must have gone wrong with the system when I installed or updated other packages.

I just performed a fresh reinstall in order to test this and it still is not working, out of the box.

Here are the messages I am getting from qjackctl: https://pastebin.com/1S6DS5B1

Prior to reinstalling Ubuntu Studio, I attempted killing jackd and jackdbus processes and starting jack from the command line, rather than from qjackctl, but it did not help (neither did disabling DBUS or killing pulseaudio).

Comment: Use qjackctl to start and stop JACK server. qjackctl must be set to correct sound device before use. qjackctl in Studio has d-bus enabled by default, to control Pulseaudio and JACK sharing audio devices

Comment: I actually have since resolved the issue and also discovered why none of the traditional JACK fixes worked: It was just a matter of my laptop's internal hardware being incompatible (and apparently this is a common issue with this hardware).  

External audio interfaces have all worked fine.

For future reference, in case it helps anyone having the same issue, my internal audio information is

`card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]`